# Statically allocated global memory struct in CUDA

Tags: memory-management, cuda

Is this definition of `static` global memory `struct` possible in CUDA?

```
struct ABC
{
    int nIntArray[3];
    float rFLoatArray[3];
};

__device__ static ABC xABCStruct = {{1, 2, 3}, {1.f, 2.f, 3.f}};
```

How can I watch this struct instance in CUDA memory?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. Take a look at the following code, showing also an example on how accessing it:

```
#include<stdio.h>

/********************/
/* CUDA ERROR CHECK */
/********************/
#define gpuErrchk(ans) { gpuAssert((ans), __FILE__, __LINE__); }
inline void gpuAssert(cudaError_t code, char *file, int line, bool abort=true)
{
    if (code != cudaSuccess) 
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"GPUassert: %s %s %d\n", cudaGetErrorString(code), file, line);
        if (abort) exit(code);
    }
}

struct ABC { int nIntArray[3]; float rFLoatArray[3];};

__device__ static ABC xABCStruct = {{1, 2, 3}, {1.f, 2.f, 3.f}};

__device__ static float test_float = 3.f;

__global__ void kernel1() { printf("%f\n", test_float); }

__global__ void kernel2() { 
    printf("%i\n", xABCStruct.nIntArray[0]); 
    printf("%i\n", xABCStruct.nIntArray[1]); 
    printf("%i\n", xABCStruct.nIntArray[2]); 
    printf("%f\n", xABCStruct.rFLoatArray[0]); 
    printf("%f\n", xABCStruct.rFLoatArray[1]); 
    printf("%f\n", xABCStruct.rFLoatArray[2]); 
}

void main() {
    kernel1<<<1,1>>>();
    gpuErrchk(cudaPeekAtLastError());
    gpuErrchk(cudaDeviceSynchronize());

    kernel2<<<1,1>>>();
    gpuErrchk(cudaPeekAtLastError());
    gpuErrchk(cudaDeviceSynchronize());
}
```

Comment: Thx jack.
I am using this device struct in host function like following.
__device__ ABC xABCStruct2 = {{1, 2, 3}, {1.f, 2.f, 3.f}};
void assign()
{
__device__ ABC xABCStruct1;
xABCStruct1 = xABCStruct2;}
in this case, assign is achieved? and i can't watch memory in debug time.
In a word, can i operate with device variable in host function? and watch it while debugging?

Comment: You cannot use `__device__` variables directly in host functions, except `cudaMemcpyToSymbol` and `cudaMemcpyFromSymbol`.  You can watch device variables while debugging if you are doing device debugging, using one of the device debuggers, such as Nsight VSE or cuda-gdb.